# How to get current cart values using WC_Shortcodes?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode

I am trying to get current cart items from my own plugin using WC_Shortcodes::cart(); this will return cart details in html format.

WC()->cart->get_cart();

code not working. i need only cart data without html format. please advise thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value by using the global var

```
 global $woocommerce;

 $cart_value = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
```

Or

```
WC()->cart->total
```